# Mask failure message in GeoPosition?

Tags: dataset, geographics, message-coding

I am trying to construct a variable in a dataset that calculates the distance from a point to a city/country listed in another variable. I hoped to use GeoPosition to get the approximate location of the city or country. Sometimes these are "locations" that GeoPosition cannot find, and I'm happy to accept a blank or missing value as the location, but GeoPosition gives a failure message:
[image: GeoPosition failure with nonsense city]

The failure message seems to cause the dataset variable processing to halt. I cannot seem to suppress or mask the failure message (Quiet doesn't work). Any suggestions on how to gracefully handle a GeoPosition failure by returning a blank and continuing on to process the remaining rows in the dataset?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `FailureQ`:

```
If[FailureQ[#], {}, #] &@Interpreter["Location"]["Paris"]
```

> GeoPosition[{48.86, 2.34}]

```
If[FailureQ[#], {}, #] &@Interpreter["Location"]["ParisBerlin"]
```

> {}